# How to move, rotate polygon in openlayers 4.x?

Tags: openlayers

I have a openlayers 4.x project where I am drawing polygon. I want to move polygon on openlayers map and also want to rotate the polygon so that points inside the polygon also rotate together, is it possible?

Comment: To do it programatically use feature.getGeometry().translate() and feature.getGeometry().rotate().  For user interactions openlayers has ol.interaction.Translate but for rotate you would need a third party add-on such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/ol-rotate-feature/v/1.4.2

Comment: @Mike thanks for your comment, how to use this third party add-on  npmjs.com/package/ol-rotate-feature/v/1.4.2 in my typescript project?

Comment: I'm not familiar with typescript but for most OL4 users adding `<script src="https://unpkg.com/ol-rotate-feature@latest/dist/bundle.min.js"></script>` or a link to your own copy of that (or the more readable bundle.js in the same path) would work.  Follow the link to the demo and then view source to see how it's done and how select and rotate interactions are added to the map.

Answer (score 2):

You can try the ol/interaction/Transform.
http://viglino.github.io/ol-ext/examples/interaction/map.interaction.transform.html

It's an interaction to translate, rotate and scale any feature on the map. You can also rotate many features at a time or change the rotation center.